# loop string and replace

Tags: c#, file, replace

I have a very long string which is read from an XML file.
I need to loop through this string and find the following params:

```
CreatedBy="?"
```

I then want to replace what is inside the "" with a integer so lets call this myValue. How can I search each place where it finds CreatedBy=" and replace what it finds next until the ending " with myValue?

```
int myValue = 7;
string myXml = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

Comment: take a look at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument instead of parsing a string

Comment: You would be much better to parse the XML, otherwise just replace that substring with an almost identical one (with a different number)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
 myXml = myXml.Replace("CreatedBy=\"?\"", "CreatedBy=\"7\"");
```

But as some of the comments suggest, you would probably be better off, if you read your XML into an XDocument and manipulate the data through that object.

**Edit:**
If you don't know the value of CreatedBy (but if you know it's an integer), you can use Regex to do something like this

```
int myVal = 7;
Regex regex = new Regex("CreatedBy=\"[0-9]*\"");
myXml = regex.Replace(myXml, String.Format("CreatedBy=\"{0}\"", myVal));
```

Still, it would be much more readable and easier to understand, if you used an `XDocument` object.

Comment: What if I do not know what is inside the CreatedBy"?"

Comment: @John I've updated the answer with an example that uses Regular Expressions. But you should really consider using an XDocument instead. You might end up with invalid XML if the replacement fails.

Comment: @John, did you solve your problem? If my answer helped, please consider accepting it :-)